# How to set <img> height as <h1>'s height?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to set the `<img>`'s height to use `<h1></h1>`'s height.

For example: the `<h1></h1>` height is 10em, so I want the `<img>`'s height is 10 em as well.
But the problem is I don't know the exact height of `<h1></h1>` on each web browser.

I tried to set `<img>`'s height in percents but it did't work. What should I do?

Here is my original code:

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-top: 1%;">
    <div class="large-9 columns">
        <h1><img src="img/UnionJR.png"> <a href="subjectlist.html#BrE" class="logo">English</a></h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Img">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and this kind of works for Chrome. (I haven't tried with the others)

```html
<h1><img src="img/UnionJR.png" style="height: 1em;"> <a href="subjectlist.html#BrE" class="logo">English</a></h1>
```

It seems like a bad way to slove this problem but for brief work it will do.

Anyway, I still want to know other methods. Please add more!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something here, if your h1 has a specific height set e.g.

```
h1 {
  height: 10em;
}
```

you should be able to use

```
h1 img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Percentage heights do work if their parent element has a specific height set.
Just tried this in chrome and it works - the image takes the height of the h1.

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <div class="row" style="margin-top: 1%;">
    <div class="large-9 columns">
        <h1><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Img"> <a href="subjectlist.html#BrE" class="logo">English</a></h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Img">
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    h1 {
        height: 10em;
    }
    h1 img {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, however I want to answer this for anyone looking for a solution like I was.

A solution I found worked was to use this css

```
.imgh1 {
background-image: image.png;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
```

And apply it to your header like this

```
<h1 class="imgh1">&nbsp;</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting a class for both the `<h1>` and the `<img>` tag.

Something like

```
<h1 class='tall'>
  <img class='tall' src="img/UnionJR.png"> 
  <a href="subjectlist.html#BrE" class="logo">English</a>
</h1>
```

with a style:

```
.tall {
  height: 800px;
}
```

Keep in mind, however, that using em means that nested elements (if height is defined with em) will multiply by their parent height. So if your heading is 10 em, and your img is 10 em, the image will actually display at 100em or height. (10x10).

I would suggest using a pixel based height in this scenario, since it won't [compound the way the em does](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2014/04/css-understanding-em-and-rem.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could add some rule to your CSS file for specific browser and overwrite the any style originally applied:

```
h1 {
    -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fixed height for the `<h1>` tag and apply `height: inherit; max-height: 100%; min-height: 100%;` to the image to always keep them of same height. Just keep note that your image should be of specific dimensions to avoid the blurring on applying min and max height styles.

```
img {
    height: inherit;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%
}
h1 {
    height: 50px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ttqfaoak/1/)**